How do I generate Entity Framework Core models at compile time using .NET 9?
I recently migrated my WPF app to .NET 9 and was eager to try out the new compile-time features for EF Core.
My setup looks as follows: I have a file that implements the rest of the partial DbContext class:
public partial class Schule_als_Staat_DbContext : DbContext
{
    public Schule_als_Staat_DbContext()
    { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // Wenn bereits konfiguriert wurde, brauchen wir nicht nochmal
        if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            return;

        DatenbankInfos? dbInfos = ConnectionInfoService.DatenbankInfos;

        // Wenn dbInfo null ist, wird Benutzer auf Server-Info-Seite weitergeleitet
        if (dbInfos == null)
        {
            Navigator.NavigateToPage(new ServerInformationenEntryPage());
            return;
        }

        string dbConnectString = dbInfos.GetConnectString();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(dbConnectString);
    }
}

This is just there so my EF Core models don't loose their connect string logic (because the connect string is loaded dynamically from disk) when updating models.
I also set the configuration in my .csproj project file to generate the compile time models when the application is built:
<EFOptimizeContext>true</EFOptimizeContext>
<EFScaffoldModelStage>build</EFScaffoldModelStage>

However, when I build the application, I get the following error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'Schule_als_Staat_DbContext'.
The exception 'The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

This was thrown while attempting to create an instance.
For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
The documentation in the link states that I have to setup something like this:
public class SaSDesignTimeFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<Schule_als_Staat_DbContext>
{
    public Schule_als_Staat_DbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Schule_als_Staat_DbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=schule-als-staat;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;");

        return new Schule_als_Staat_DbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}

Which I did, but I still got the same error.
My goal is to have the dynamic connect string loading via the OnConfiguring() method in the DbContext, but also have the precompiled models.
Does anybody know how to fix this? Even though it's fairly new technology.

"The calling thread must be STA" sounds like you're trying to interact with the UI from a background thread. Which should have nothing to do with a DbContext.

It seem quite odd to get this exception at build time. Does any part of your DbContext call out to external components? Like an UI? Navigator.NavigateToPage seem a bit rather suspicious.

just there so my EF Core models don't loose their connect string logic that logic should not be inside the DbContext. This code is causing the problem to begin with, by trying to create a GUI when you run EF tools from the console. The docs explain [how to handle connection strings and configuration at design/build time

To fix the problem remove the code in OnConfiguration and create a DbContext constructor that accepts DbContextOptions<ThatContext>, eg public ThatContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options):base(options){}. That's what accepts the configuration from the DI middleware or design factory. You may not have to create a design factory at all if you use the Generic Host in your application

If you want to create the connection string interactively, you can create the options using DbContextOptionsBuilder and store the object it in a static property or register it as a singleton. That should be used any time you create the DbContext with new ThatContext(options), eg new ThatContext(TheOptions.Value). If you use DI, the constructor will be called with the registered object automatically
